# Issue about Tomcat 5.5 "ROOT" directory

Tags: tomcat

Now I specify a directory name for "appBase" attribute on "{TomcatHome}/config/server.xml".

```
<host appBase="d:/aaa">
      <Context docBase="d:/aaa/bbb"> </Context>
</host>
```

When I navigate URL to "http://localhost:8080", TOMCAT think "d:/aaa/ROOT" as application directory.

I want to know how can I modify this mechanism to make TOMCAT auto search my specified directory.

For example: When I input "http://localhost:8080", TOMCAT would search "d:/aaa/{SpecifiedDirectoryName}/"

Answer (score 0):

I create "ROOT.xml" in {TOMCAT_HOME}/{ENGINE}/{HOST} directory specifying a new "context" in it. 
   So the question be solved.